# Cn1 dialog box height auto fix

Tags: codenameone

I have a dialog box that has picker and other components. I need its height auto fix where the last component ends. In the pic below, it should end after submit button.

[image]

Code:

```
Dialog selectDialog = new Dialog();
selectDialog.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
selectDialog.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);

Container pickerContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());

Picker p = new Picker();
p.setStrings(outlets);

Label arrowLabel = new Label(pickerIcon);
arrowLabel.setUIID("Container");
pickerContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, p);
pickerContainer.add(BorderLayout.EAST, arrowLabel);

Label nameLabel = new Label("Name");
Label nameData = new Label("Santosh Kandel");
Label locationLabel = new Label("Location");
Label locationData = new Label("Baneswor");
Label timeLabel = new Label("Time");
Label timeData = new Label("09:47");
Label dateLabel = new Label("Date");
Label dateData = new Label("2017-2-10");

TableLayout dialogTable = new TableLayout(7, 2);
Container attendenceTableContainer = new Container(dialogTable);
attendenceTableContainer.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 50, 50);
attendenceTableContainer.add(dialogTable.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), nameLabel)
    .add(dialogTable.createConstraint().widthPercentage(70), nameData)
    .add(dialogTable.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), locationLabel)
    .add(dialogTable.createConstraint().widthPercentage(70), locationData)
    .add(dialogTable.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), timeLabel)
    .add(dialogTable.createConstraint().widthPercentage(70), timeData)
    .add(dialogTable.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), dateLabel)
    .add(dialogTable.createConstraint().widthPercentage(70), dateData);

Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");

selectDialog.add(pickerContainer);
selectDialog.add(attendenceTableContainer);
selectDialog.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(submitButton));
selectDialog.showAtPosition(200, 200, 50, 50, false);
```

I tried d.showPopupDialog(component) but it didnot place the dialog where I wanted. Here I want it at the top of the form with some margin and in some cases at a specif location as well. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use showStretched or showPacked depending on if you want the Dialog to take up the screen width or resized to fit the size of the widest component, and you can define the position it should popup at:

```
selectDialog.setAutoDispose(false);
selectDialog.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);
selectDialog.setTransitionInAnimator(CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, false, 300));
selectDialog.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, true, 800));
selectDialog.showStretched(BorderLayout.NORTH, true);
```